# tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(output_shapes=...) vs flow_from_directory(target_size=...)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

As mentioned in the title, what's the difference between the two?

If i have this code:

```
train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10,
                                    width_shift_range=10,
                                    height_shift_range=10,
                                    zoom_range=0.3,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    vertical_flip=True,
                                    fill_mode='constant',
                                    cval=0,
                                    rescale=1./255)



train_gen = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(training_dir,
                                           batch_size=bs,
                                           classes=classes, #se non viene fornito, viene dedotto automaticamente dalla struttura delle cartelle
                                           class_mode='categorical',
                                           shuffle=True,
                                           seed=SEED)  # targets are directly converted into one-hot vectors
```

I can generate the dataset with:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: train_gen,
                                           output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
                                           output_shapes=([None, img_h, img_w, 3], [None, num_classes]))
```

where `img_h` and `img_w` are my generated images output size.

Then i can call the `.fit` method in order to train my network:

```
model.fit(x=train_dataset,
      epochs=100,  #### set repeat in training dataset
      steps_per_epoch=len(train_gen),
      validation_data=valid_dataset,
      validation_steps=len(valid_gen), 
      callbacks=callbacks)
```

On the other hand i could just declare the `target_size` inside my `generator`, and then call the `fit_generator` function:

```
  train_gen = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(training_dir,
                                       batch_size=bs,
                                       classes=classes,

                                       target_size=(img_h, img_w), #CHANGED LINE OF CODE!

                                       class_mode='categorical',
                                       shuffle=True,
                                       seed=SEED)  # targets are directly converted into one-hot vectors
```

and then:

```
model.fit_generator(....)
```

What's the difference between the two approaches? My goal is to simply do data augmentation over a train dataset and resize all the images in order to fit the input size of my Convolutional Neural Network.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fit_generator` means that the generator is run in parallel to the model, for efficiency. For instance, this allows you to do real-time data augmentation on images on CPU in parallel to training your model on GPU.

The ImageDataGenerator methods: `flow()`, `flow_from_directory()` and `flow_from_dataframe()` allows you to read the images from a big numpy array and folders containing images.

Comment: fit_generator can save time if you are using GPU

Comment: But what's the difference between resizing the input image in ``.from_generator`` and ``target_size=...`` ?